# Let $X$ be any set. Prove there exist a vector space $V$ such that $X$ is a basis for $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, free-modules

> Let $X$ be any set. Prove there exist a vector space $V$ such that $X$ is a basis for $V$.

For example what would be the Vector space $V$ such that $X=\mathbb{N}$ is a basis? I don't really see any hint, perhaps if it's finite dimentional. Also we must take care about over which Field $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: For any ring $R$ and a set $X$, you can construct something called a free $R$-module  $V$ with $X$ as its basis: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module#Formal_linear_combinations In the case that $R$ is a field, $V$ will be a vector space.

Comment: This is new to me, I'm gonna check it out, thanks!

Comment: @uniquesolution Well, if the OP wants a vector space, he better choose $R$ to be a field! My point is that he is free to choose **any** field he wants. $R$ can  be $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Q}$, etc.

Comment: @ZeroXLR: Note that there is no evidence that the OP is male. Our unconscious biases will make us assume (often without us noticing) that people in mathematics are male; and the outcome of those assumptions will exacerbate the problem of excluding women.

Comment: @GregMartin I am quite careful with my words: the OP mentions that he is a "*Male* graduate student" on his profile https://math.stackexchange.com/users/546116/ipreferpi and I have no reason to believe he is lying.

Comment: @ZeroXLR The profile actually says "*Math* graduate student".

Comment: @A.Γ. Hmm I must have been half-asleep when I looked at the profile.

Answer (score 2):

For any countable set $X$ with members $x_i$ we can define the formal sums $\sum \lambda_i x_i$ where the coefficients $\lambda_i$ are members of a field such as $\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. The set of formal sums becomes a vector space if we define addition and scalar multiplication in the natural way:

$(\sum \lambda_i x_i) + (\sum \kappa_i x_i) = \sum (\lambda_i + \kappa_i)x_i$

$\kappa (\sum \lambda_i x_i) = \sum (\kappa \lambda_i) x_i$

Comment: Almost. I think you want only finite sums if $X$ is to be a basis,  even though $X$ may be infinite. And then $X$ can have any cardinality. Any field will do for coefficients. Technically speaking, $X$ is not even a subset of the vector space. $1x$ is there but $x$ is not.